# Can a header file cooperate with code in main?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've read that an `#include header.h` is a preprocessor (because of `#`), which means it gets processed before compilation.
Is that why my code can't run? Because I'm trying to make an if statement in main with my function from my header(that takes a parameter) and it won't work.

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
test(46);

if (test() > 30){
    cout << "great";
}
else{
    cout << "It needs to be higher";
}


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Header.h**

```
using namespace std;

    int test(int x){
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Don't put `using namespace` inside of header files, it can give unwanted side effects on the long term

Comment: your test function takes an argument, but when you call it you are not providing any. Is it a typo?

Comment: Why don't you pass an argument to test in `if (test() > 30)`

Comment: Replace the `#include` directive with the code in that header. You'll have **exactly** the same problems. `#include` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't the problem. I suspect you might be getting a compiler error message (or linker error) because you have declared `test(int x)` with an integer parameter and then you call it with no parameter, e.g.: `test()`.

I've modified your code to include an integer `result`:

```
int main(){
    int result = test(46); // Save the result of calling the function

    if (result > 30){ // Test the value of the result
        cout << "great";
    }
    else{
        cout << "It needs to be higher";
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aah I see. I thought it was enough to declare my test as test(46) and then use it in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The test function in Header.h file takes a int as parameter.But in your code you lose it.Pass a int to test function like this.

```
if (test(42) > 30)
```

You will get the output: great.

Comment: Okay, so the header doesn't transfer the int datatype over in main?

Comment: @HamSelv The header file contains declarations and definitions, that are meant to be used exactly the way as they were declared. So in the main file the compiler knows that `test()` returns `int` and needs to be passed a parameter of type `int`.